# user defined type not defined- don't know what is wrong

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know what is wrong here. I have this inside a module.
I keeps getting

> user defined type not defined

```
Type film
    id As Integer
End Type

Sub testfilm()

Dim newfilm As film
newfilm.id = 99

End Sub
```

Comment: is the type public or private

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Type film
    id As Integer
End Type

Sub testfilm()

Dim newfilm As film
newfilm.id = 99

End Sub
```

According to this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262341(v=vs.60).aspx), modules from forms require only private types. When you don't tell if the type is private or public, the Dim keyword forces the type to public

Comment: I just have my type declaration after so many sub. so what i need to do is to move it all way to the beginning. Thank you though